# What is the current status of GCJ at the moment (mid 2009)?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

What is the current status of GCJ at the moment (mid 2009)?

The latest news are from 2007, so I'm wondering if there is any form of progress? I remember that there was a while ago a compiled version of lucene available which used gcj to compile it from the java sources. Is there any other high profile project which uses gcj at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

The news page hasn't been updated, but if you look through the [changelogs for GCC 4.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html) there is still active work ongoing. It can handle Java source up to 1.5.

Answer (score -1):

GCJ is not Java.

Consider looking at OpenJDK.

Comment: What do you mean? Since when is OpenJDK able to compile java code to binary executables?

Comment: Why do you want to compile java code to binary executables?
It's pointless and, actually, slow.

Comment: Because I want to make some client libraries available to C/C++ users without to rewrite this stuff in C/C++. And I don't want to have the users to have Java installed as well.